# Stochastic Connection Between Elliptic and Parabolic PDE

Tags: stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, parabolic-pde

This question is something on the lines for what I am looking for, [Estimates for parabolic vs elliptic PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379652/estimates-for-parabolic-vs-elliptic-pde).

For certain elliptic PDE's, we can show the stochastic representation of a solution to the PDE looks somewhat similar to the Feynman-Kac formula as on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula, with the time variable replaced with a stopping time, call it $\tau$. Given the solution of an elliptic PDE, I can go ahead and take $\tau=t$ in the formula to recover the solution for a parabolic PDE as stated on the wiki page. Is there a method for me to go the opposite way:
Starting from the solution to the parabolic PDE, can I convert this solution to that of an elliptic PDE.

For simplicity, consider that we have a parabolic PDE of the form:
\begin{aligned}
   &\mathcal{A}u(t,x)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x)-q(t,x)u(t,x)=0,\\
    &u(0,x)=f(x),
    \end{aligned}
and the elliptic PDE
\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{A}v(x)-r(x)v(x)=0,\\
    &v(x)=f(x).
    \end{aligned}

Now I believe by recalculating the generator $\mathcal{A}$ that the derivative vanishes when we 'stop' the solution from the parabolic PDE at time $\tau$ to give the elliptic PDE equation. I haven't seen anything treating the two problems as one, although it seems as if they are very closely linked so I thought this should be possible. My question is: if I were very lazy and derived one of these PDE's, could I get the other one for free?

I would like to turn something like
$$u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-\int^T_t q(s,X_s)ds}f(X_T)|X_t=x]$$
into
$$v(x)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-\int^\tau_0 r(s,X_s)ds}f(X_\tau)|X_0=x]$$